# Stop reinserting entity when creating a reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The problem is that when I insert entityA to my database, then I read entityA from the database and set it as a reference to entityB, it's reinserting entityA, so I end up with a duplicate entityA.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ISmartFridgeDALFacade dal = new SmartFridgeDALFacade("SmartFridgeDb");

    var uow = dal.GetUnitOfWork();
    var list = new List("testing");       
    uow.ListRepo.Add(list);
    uow.SaveChanges();
    dal.DisposeUnitOfWork();

    uow = dal.GetUnitOfWork();
    var test = uow.ListRepo.Get(list.ListId);
    var item = new Item("Meat");
    uow.ItemRepo.Add(item);
    var listitem = new ListItem(1, 500, "g", null, test, item);
    uow.ListItemRepo.Add(listitem);
    uow.SaveChanges();
    dal.DisposeUnitOfWork();
}

public void Add(T entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling SaveChanges twice?

Comment: It's a test, simulating you are doing it at different times. I also dispose my Unit of Work and create it again.

Comment: The parts where the essential stuff is happening are invisible to us. This repo and uow layer conceals context initialization and lifespan, and leaves us guessing what happens inside `Add` etc.

Comment: @Thisen Is your `Get` method hitting the database or is it retrieving `test` from a cache? I think the problem is that `item ` is not been tracked by the context at the point of the `Add` and therefore is put in the added state.

Comment: Yeah, as @GertArnold said, because you are not directly working with context it's hard to guess what's happening.